# C2264 cannot convert argument 1 from 'Vector' to 'float *'

Tags: c++

I recently started to get into C++ and am slowly learning. Right now I'm trying to get a broken cheat to fully function. I have a problem that i cant seem to solve though.

Visual shows the errors

`Error (active) E0413   no suitable conversion function from "Vector" to "float`

``` Error  C2664   ``bool CanHit(float *,const Vector &)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'Vector' to 'float * ```

```
#pragma endregion Get the list of things to scan

// check hits
// check hits
for (auto HitBoxID : HitBoxesToScan)
{
    if (AWall)
    {
        Vector Point = GetHitboxPosition(pEntity, HitBoxID);
        float Damage = 0.f;
        Color c = Color(255, 255, 255, 255);
        if (CanHit(Point, &Damage))
        {
            c = Color(0, 255, 0, 255);
            if (Damage >= Menu::Window.RageBotTab.AccuracyMinimumDamage.GetValue())
            {
                return HitBoxID;
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (GameUtils::IsVisible(hackManager.pLocal(), pEntity, HitBoxID))
            return HitBoxID;
    }
}

return -1;
```

Comment: Change `CanHit(Point, &Damage)` to `CanHit( &Damage, Point)`

Comment: I recommend you rename your `Vector` class so that it doesn't confuse readers with `std::vector<>`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just have the arguments the wrong way round for your `CanHit` invocation.

You should instead call it like:

```
if (CanHit(&Damage, Point))
{
    ...
}
```

You can tell as your error message shows you the type it was *expecting* (`bool CanHit(float *,const Vector &)`), but you're passing in a `Vector` then a `float *` (the wrong way round).

Comment: Thank you. Now that I fixed it the errors are now
Error C2061 syntax error: identifier 'CanHit' 
Error C2143 syntax error: missing ';' before '{'

Comment: @boot Update your question to show your new code - you've made a syntax error, but without seeing the new code it's impossible to point out where. I'd guess you're missing a closing bracket on your `if` statement, though.

Comment: No. @boot do not cause the question to sprawl. New problem unrelated to the old problem is a new question.

Comment: @user4581301 Alright. & I fixed the syntax error but still get an error when trying to build the solution stating                                 `>RageBot.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "bool __cdecl CanHit(float *,class Vector const &)" (?CanHit@@YA_NPAMABVVector@@@Z) referenced in function "private: int __thiscall CRageBot::HitScan(class IClientEntity *)" (?HitScan@CRageBot@@AAEHPAVIClientEntity@@@Z)`

Comment: @boot You misunderstood user4581301 - each question on SO should be for a single distinct issue. This question is now solved, you should mark an answer (if a post helped), then post your current problem as a new question.

Comment: Understood. Thanks for the help.